# Can one disable message truncation in Yahoo mail?

Tags: yahoo-mail

Currently, Yahoo mail presents only the beginning of long emails followed by the message: `This message has been truncated` on the left hand side and a `Show Full Message` button on the right hand side. Clicking the button recovers the full message.

Can this message truncation be disabled?